# Maven: Add Test Directory From Command Line

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, junit4

Is there a way to include a test folder for Maven to compile from the command line?

I have a set of tests that are in a folder that are not part of the standard set of unit and integration tests. These tests are still useful to run individually until the needed integration tests are built. In Eclipse, I can run these tests individually by right clicking on them and running them as a JUnit test. I am finding that I often want to run more than one test, so I am trying to run them from Maven on the command line. In Maven I can do something like this:

```
mvn -Dtest=OldTest,OlderTest test
```

The problem I think I have is that the folder that these tests sit in is not listed as part of the set of test files that need to compile in the POM. I would like to temporarily add the folder, run the tests, and remove the folder without modifying the POM.

Comment: Tests should always run which is true for unit tests. If we are talking about integration-tests this is different. For such purposes the integration-test life cycle part exists and the naming convention for that (*IT.java etc.) This can be supported by the maven-failsafe-plugin. For such things you like to do i would create a separate module in maven and make a profile inside the module which can be used to run those tests or not (mvn -Polder-tests)...Adding source folder etc. dynamically is never a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Build Helper plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) to add in integration test sources when a certain profile has been activated, for example:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>add-test-source</id>
        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <sources>
                <source>src/it/java</source>
            </sources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Perhaps you can do something similar?

Comment: That accomplishes something similar, but I am looking for a way to add the test source from the command line without needing to edit the POM.